# Throw Exception still remains 'SUCCESS' state in aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, exception

My aura component still retrieve a response with 'SUCCESS' state even though I threw Exception.
My aura component's controller

```
handleApproval: {
 var recordId = cmp.get("v.recordId");
 var action = cmp.get("c.handleApproval");
 action.setParams({
  recordId: recordId
 });
 action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
  console.log("result: ", JSON.stringify(response));
  var state = response.getState();
  console.log("state: ", state); //retrun SUCCESS here
 }
}
```

my Apex Controller:

```
[...]
@AuraEnabled
public static String handleApproval(String recordId) {
 String error = null
 try {
  [...]
  if(condition) { // condition returns true
   error = 'Failed to submit for approval';
   throw new AuraHandledException(error);
  }
  [...]
 } catch (Exception e) {
  error = 'Failed to submit for approval. Error: ' + e.getMessage();
 }
}
[...]
```

How can I return 'ERROR' state in this case? Please help.

Comment: According to the partial code posted, you threw exception in the `if` block, but it has been catched from the same apex apex method and never rethrew, so the method didn't *fail*, that's why you see `SUCCESS` in the aura component.

Comment: Thanks @RubenDG, I throw an exception in catch blocks and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the exception is catched by the same method, so it never *fails*, therefore the state returned in the aura component is `SUCCESS`.

In order to get the `ERROR` state you should rethrow the exception in the catch block:

```java
try {
    [...]
    if(condition) { // condition returns true
        error = 'Failed to submit for approval';
        throw new AuraHandledException(error);
    }
    [...]
} catch (Exception e) {
    error = 'Failed to submit for approval. Error: ' + e.getMessage();
    throw e; // rethrow the Exception
}
```