# Can AuraHandledExceptions appear on an Aura component without being processed by an action callback function?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, exception, error-messages

I have a custom error page that should appear every time an error appears from the middle/back end. I have an Aura component that is using this. This Aura component has 4 actions that call its Apex controller. Each of them, if anything but a SUCCESS response occurs, pull up the custom error page. However, there is an error, in a Trigger, that seems to bypass the action callback method and display an error on the Salesforce page when it occurs. Is this supposed to be able to happen or am I missing something? Essentially, what seems to be happening is that an AuraHandledException is coming through with a SUCCESS response.

```
action.setCallback(this, (response) => {
            if (response.getState() == 'SUCCESS') {
                console.log('inside success save*********Detail')
                //other code
                    let appEvent;
                    appEvent = $A.get("e.c:SaveModalEvt");
                    appEvent.setParams({//params});
                    appEvent.fire();
               //other code
            }
            else {
                helper.setErrorPageVisibility(component, true)
                let appEvent;
                appEvent = $A.get("e.c:SaveModalEvt");
                appEvent.setParams({//params});
                appEvent.fire();
            }
            helper.hideSpinner(component,event,helper);
```

This Trigger was created to test error handling functionality.

```
trigger *****breakTrigger on ******** (before insert,before update,after insert,after update) {

    throw new AuraHandledException('Hello');
}
```

Comment: Without specific code, it's impossible to tell you what's happening. Can you please [edit] your question to include the relevant code?

Comment: @sfdcfox alright, added

Comment: Closer. What's the Apex being called?

Comment: save***********Detail

Comment: Yes, but we'd need to see at least some of that actual method.

Comment: @sfdcfox the method works and does what it's supposed to. It's the introduction of this new Trigger that is causing the issue

Comment: How you handle the DML operation in your `save*****detail` method will reveal the problem. If you absolutely don't want to share, fine, but you'll get an answer that only speculates on the cause of the problem rather than definitively stating the problem and solution.

Answer (score 0):

Historically, exceptions used to be thrown up the stack through trigger boundaries. This was fixed some time ago. Any exception thrown in a trigger will have specific behavior based on the DML operation.

## allOrNone = true

When this flag is set, which is default, a DmlException will be thrown, rather than the original exception.

```
try {
  insert accountRecord;
} catch(AuraHandledException ex) {
  Assert.fail('We should never get here.');
} catch(DmlException ex) {
  System.debug('Error was: '+ex.getMessage());
  // Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, triggerName:
  // execution of BeforeInsert (AfterInsert, etc)
  // caused by: System.AuraHandledException: Script-thrown exception
  // Trigger.triggerName: line X, column Y: []
}
```

## allOrNone = false

Specifying this operation specifically will never throw a catchable exception.

```
Database.SaveResult result = Database.insert(accountRecord, false);
  // execution of BeforeInsert (AfterInsert, etc)
  // caused by: System.AuraHandledException: Script-thrown exception
  // Trigger.triggerName: line X, column Y
System.debug(result.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
```

As such, you need to create the `AuraHandledException` outside of the trigger context. You should only ever use `.addError` inside a trigger context, and you should specifically avoid throwing or allowing exceptions to be thrown inside a trigger context.

Comment: I always appreciate your assistance good sir. I think this situation was simpler. I think we had a catch block that didn't rethrow the error, so it got passed to the front with a SUCCESS status. Does that sound right? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/405577/throw-exception-still-remains-success-state-in-aura-component the checked response here is what I'm referring to.

Comment: @seekingPeace Yes, that's why I was asking for the Apex Code  If you don't let the AuraHandledException reach the top of the stack, the framework has no way to know there was an error condition.

Comment: yeah, thank you. I wasn't aware of that.